# Determine if subtracting from an unsigned int will roll over

Tags: c++

How can it be possible to determine if subtracting `n` from an `unsigned int` will roll over to a negative value, considering that casting to a `signed int` can result in a negative value already?

Example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    unsigned int i = 2147483647*2;
    if((int)i - 1 < 0){
        cout << "rolled over";
    }
    else {
        i = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In order to check if subtracting from an `unsigned int` would roll over, you could cast it to an `int` first. However, if the `unsigned int` is > the max int value, you will already end up negative. So how can I prevent an `unsigned int` from rolling over?

Comment: subtracting `n` from an `unsigned int` will never roll over to a negative value, considering unsigned types do not represent negative values.

Comment: Your research would probably have given you better results using the keywords _overflow_, _underflow_ than _"rollover"_.

Comment: If the number you are subtracting is larger than the number you are subtracting from, you get a negative value. For unsigned integers in c++, this is performed with modulo arithmetic, so would "wrap around". Just compare the two operators.

Comment: In this particular example: `if (i < 1)`.

Comment: Assuming `i` is the value of the unsigned int, and `n` is the amount being subtracted, then `if (i < n) cout << "value underflow";` .  Depending on your use case, it may be appropriate to throw an error, to allow the underflow to wrap around, to log a message, and/or to pin the value to some minimum (e.g., `0`).